# Possible to make a method with random type?

Tags: c#, silverlight, types

Greetings

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a single method with a random type.

Something like:

```
public static T CheckWhatTIs(object source)
{
    MessageBox.Show("T = " + T.GetType());
}
```

where I would get "T = bool" when I use it as CheckWhatTIs(true);
and get "T = int" when I use it as CheckWhatTIs(1);

Is it possible to accomplish this ?

Comment: Wondering what is driving you to have this!

Comment: In this case, it may not matter, but for the next time: you should not mention T in the extension methods name, since T is nothing the caller is aware of. What about `true.ShowType()`?

Comment: Basicly I wanted this information to change 
(bool)SomeObject to GetValue<bool>(SomeObject);

Comment: Please create a new question for GetParameterValue. This is not a forum where you just discuss things, there is a question-answers structure which doesn't work when the question changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static void CheckWhatTIs<T>(T source)
{
    MessageBox.Show("T = " + source.GetType());
}
```

Few remarks:

1. The function has no return type as you are just showing a message box
2. If you want to use it as `CheckWhatTIs(1)` and `CheckWhatTIs(true)` don't declare it as an extension method, remove `this` from the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

It depends whether you want to display the type of `T`, or the type of the object that the parameter refers to.

Consider:

```
public static void ShowTypes<T>(T item)
{
    Console.WriteLine("T = " + typeof(T));
    Console.WriteLine("item.GetType() = " + item.GetType());
}
```

Now imagine:

```
ShowTypes<object>("foo");
```

That's entirely valid, but the type of `T` is System.Object, whereas the type of the object is System.String.

You should also consider what you want to happen with:

```
ShowTypes<string>(null); // Will print System.String then explode
```

and

```
int? x = 10;
ShowTypes<int?>(x); // Will print System.Nullable<System.Int32>
                    // and then System.Int32
```