# Question concerning T types

Tags: c#, silverlight, generics

From my question @ [Possible to make a method with random type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270671/possible-to-make-a-method-with-random-type) I got this:

```
public static T GetParameterValue<T>(Parameter source)
{
    return (T)source.Value;
}
```

Now I wonder if it Is also possible to change it in any way so I can set T to the Parameter.Type?

So `GetParameterValue(ABoolParameter)` where `ABoolParameter.Type = bool, ABoolParameter.Value=true`

and have it return as a bool with it's value set to true?

and for a string:

`GetParameterValue(AStringParameter)` where `AStringParameter.Type = string, AStringParameter.Value = "somestring"`

and have it return as a string with it's value set to "somestring"?

So it should return a bool without me declaring T as a bool before?

Comment: How does your `Parameter` class look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can do that.  And even if you can, it may be a bit confusing for other (more novice) developers to read/maintain the code.

Alternatively, you can use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) (or even plain ol' [object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

Comment: I believe it isn't possible either so I assume your answer is correct and I will stick with the method I have now.

Comment: I do suggest you check out dynamic.  While not type-safe, it's pretty useful.

Comment: Kon: Dynamic actually does what I want but I can't use dynamic in switches and thus makes the methods useless in my current project :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking this?

```
public static void SetParameterValue<T>(this Parameter param, T value)
{
    param.Value = value;
    param.Type = typeof(T);
}
```

It depends on what `Type` on Parameter is. You could create a bunch of `if / else` statements if it isn't an actual `System.Type`, but it might not be the most readable thing to do.

Comment: Not what i'm looking for because initaiting this method still requires you to give the type of which you want it to be.